# How to structure ui-router to have SEO friendly url structure

Tags: angularjs, seo, angular-ui-router, url-routing

I am facing a url structure problem using ui-router in AngularJS. I want to have first level SEO friendly url structure like this:

```
https://people-profile.com/mike-david-tringe
```

So I can grab the SEO name "mike-david-tringe" via stateParam and use it to find data in database and populate the page. 
The $stateProvider has code like this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('people', {
        url: '/:nameUrl',
        templateUrl: 'app/frontend/page.tmpl.html',
        params: { 
            nameUrl: {squash: true},
        },
        controller: "PageController",
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
   .state('admin', {
        url:'/admin/:userId',
        templateUrl:'app/frontend/admin/admin.html',
        controller:'AdminController',
        controllerAs: 'admin'
   })
```

With above code, I can have https://people-profile.com/mike-david-tringe working with nameUrl = mike-david-tringe and I got SEO friendly first level url link. mike-david-tringe is SEO friendly and most important keywords beside the domain name.

But with this structure, https://people-profile.com/admin/ or https://people-profile.com/login/ will not work now. Since my controller try to grab admin as nameUrl and looking for data. And admin is not a nameUrl so my database will return null, the app will fail.

In short, stateParam nameUrl will grab anything after "/" so the url setting will think admin and login is :nameUrl but in fact, it is not.

So how do I structure my app ui-router structure to have SEO friendly url like https://people-profile.com/mike-david-tringe but when url is https://people-profile.com/admin/, it will load admin.html template and use AdminController instead as I defined in $stateProvider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is swap the order of them. The router will check in order of definition, so if /:nameUrl comes before /admin it will trigger first. But if you put /:nameUrl last then it will trigger on any url that hasn't already triggered something above.

A word of warning however. Moving between two urls that trigger the same state (like two urls that both hit /:nameUrl in your case) will not reload the controllers on the page. Only changing state will do that. There are options to change this behaviour, but it has always been very buggy for me.